# Windows Service Recovery Program - Test Windows Recovery Program

Tags: windows-services, print-spooler

So, I have a very specific problem that I am trying to solve an automate.  The breakdown of the problem is, a Registry Key entry from a Printer Driver will cause the Print Spooler service to crash and not come back.  The solution is to delete the registry key, and restart the Printer Spooler service.

I want to automate this, so when it crashes again, Windows will automatically run a batch file to delete the key and restart the service.

This is the code in my batch file.

```
reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Environments\Windows x64\Drivers\Version-3\Star TSP800II (TSP847II) /f
net start spooler
```

I have saved this bat file on the root of the drive [PrintSpoolerProperties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlnhX.png)

So, as you can see in the Recovery Tab of the Spooler Service I have this batch file supposedly running.

I cannot, for the life of me, emulate crashing the Spooler or figure out a way to test my recovery program.

Steps I have taken:
     Opened up Task Manager, went to Services Tab, Right Clicked on Spooler, Clicked go to Details, and ended the "spoolsv.exe" task.
     Opened up CMD and ran the kill PID command

How can I see if this will work?  Is there a way to force crash this service so I can see it before I deploy it on my server?

Love, an administrator who misses Linux.

Comment: LOL for missing Linux because you can't crash Windows.

Comment: LOL yeah Microsoft wrote a great tool that you can't even test.